# Understanding equation for estimating parameter for hmm with continuous observations?

Tags: parameter-estimation, hidden-markov-models

I am currently trying to understand how parameter are being reestimate for hidden markov models (hmm), using EM.

What i seem to have problems understanding what the symbol emission probability is actually modelling.  In the discrete case it would contain the probability of seeing each symbol in a given state, which analog to in continuous would be how probable a it is to see a continuous stream of observation for a given state.

The gaussian mixture model that models this probability distribution is defined by the parameters $c_{jk},\mu_{jk},\Sigma_{jk}$ for each state, in which c is each weight of all the pdf the mixture contains (indexed by $k$) and for each state $j$, and similar to $\mu$ and $\Sigma$.

And reestimation of these parameter is defined as such

\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{1}
\widetilde{c}_{jk} = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^{T}\gamma_{jk}(t)}{\sum_{t=1}^{T}\sum_{k=1}^{M}\gamma_{jk}(t)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{2}
\widetilde{\mu}_{jk} = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^{T}\gamma_{jk}(t) \cdot \boldsymbol{o_t}}{\sum_{t=1}^{T}\gamma_{jk}(t)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{3}\label{3}
    \widetilde{\Sigma}_{jk} = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^{T} \gamma_{jk}(t) \cdot (\boldsymbol{o}_t - \boldsymbol{\mu}_{jk})(\boldsymbol{o}_t - \boldsymbol{\mu}_{jk})^T}{\sum_{t=1}^{T}\gamma_{jk}(t)}
\end{equation}

$\gamma_{jk}(t)$ is the probability of being in state $j$ at time $t$ with the $k$'th mixture.

equation \eqref{1} makes sense..

Equation \eqref{1} describes the re estimate formula for $c_{jk}$, which is the ratio between the expected the number of times the system is in state $j$ using the $k$'th mixture, and the expected number of times the system is in state $j$. 
Which makes sense and it would look like it does.

What I don't get is the other equation.. why are they defined as such.. it is said that the observations weights each numerator term, but how does that help making it closer to the oberservation mean?..

similarly with the covariance matrix...

And about $\gamma_t(j,k)$ why is it defined as it is?

\begin{equation}\label{eq:y_tjk}
\gamma_{jk}(t) = \gamma_j(t)\frac{c_{jk}\mathcal{N}\left(o_t,\mu_{jk},\Sigma_{jk}\right)}{\sum_{k=1}^{\boldsymbol{M}}c_{jk}\mathcal{N}\left(o_t,\mu_{jk}, \Sigma_{jk} \right)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:update-y}
\gamma_i(t) = P(Q_t = i | O,\lambda) = \frac{\alpha_t(i)\beta_t(i)}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}\alpha_t(j)\beta_t(j)} 
\end{equation}
It stated in [pdf page 351](http://iie.fing.edu.uy/investigacion/grupos/gmm/audio/biblio/books/audio/audio_processing_techniques/Fundamentals_of_Speech_Recognition.pdf) to be fairly straight forward?
I am not fairly agreeing with them..

Why is the last part added to the equation $\gamma_jk(t)$.  (I time and (state, mixture) indexes are switched..

Comment: Your pdf link is broken

Answer (score 2):

The Maximum likelihood estimate of the mean of a Gaussian describing the probability density function of observed variables $\{\textbf{o}_{i}^{T}\} $is given by the average of the $\textbf{o}_{i}$: 
$$
\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i}^{T} \textbf{o}_{i}^{T} = \frac{\sum_{i}^{T} \textbf{o}_{i}}{\sum_{i}^{T} 1}
$$

Equation (2) is just a weighted version of the above equation. Instead of giving a the same weight $1$ to each observation $\textbf{o}_{i}$, every observation is given a weight corresponding to the probability $\gamma_{ik}$ that this observation was generated by the component $k$ of the Gaussian mixture:
 $$
\hat{\mu_{k}}= \frac{\sum_{i}^{T} \gamma_{ik}\textbf{o}_{i}}{\sum_{i}^{T} \gamma_{ik}}
$$
By using this weighed average, observations that are unlikely to come from component $k$ of the mixture (i.e. with small $\gamma_{ik}$) contribute little to the computing of the estimated mean.

The same reasoning applies to the estimation of the covariance matrix.

Comment: Could you also elaborate on why the formula $\gamma_{j,k}(t)($

Comment: @user25778 I don't understand the question in the comment. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: Added to the question..